# My code didn't work as intended and even after deleting it, it still ran

Tags: lua, roblox-studio

So originally, for some reason when I activated a text button, the code written for it didn't work as intended. The same thing happened even after I deleted the script for it.

When I clicked on it, it, instead of setting the GUI to invisible, did nothing but play a UI sound I made it play and I even tested it and the UI visibility was set to false. Then when I decided to delete it, I tested it again and still played the same UI sound effect.